# Flic Xamarin how to update to flic2

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How would i update my app from using flic to flic2
This is a xamarin.android and xamarin.ios app

i am running vs studio on mac

```
using IO.Flic.Lib;
              FlicManager.GetInstance(Android.App.Application.Context, new FlicManagerGetInstanceInitializedCallback());
```

https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/flic2lib-android/tree/master/flic2lib-android

https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/flic2lib-ios

Comment: when asking about some random library, please provide a link to its nuget or repo page

Comment: https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/flic2lib-android/tree/master/flic2lib-android

https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/flic2lib-ios